# Trying to install `idris`: The package list for 'hackage.haskell.org' does not exist. Run 'cabal update' to download it

Tags: haskell, installation, cabal, idris

UPDATE 3.

Some more tries:

```
$ curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh
Stack Version 1.1.2 already appears to be installed at:
  /usr/local/bin/stack
Use 'stack upgrade' or your OS's package manager to upgrade,
or pass '-f' to this script to over-write the existing binary, e.g.:
  curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh -s - -f
```

```
$ curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh -s - -f
Using generic bindist...

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (35) error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
curl download failed: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/releases/download/v1.7.1/stack-1.7.1-osx-x86_64.tar.gz
```

---

UPDATE 2.

No luck with running `stack` either:

```
$ stack upgrade
remote: Counting objects: 64989, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (53367/53367), done.
remote: Total 64989 (delta 17601), reused 54127 (delta 10710), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (64989/64989), 17.17 MiB | 1.48 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (17601/17601), completed with 2519 local objects.
From https://github.com/commercialhaskell/all-cabal-hashes
 + b2fd8036a5...56a8e992cb display         -> origin/display  (forced update)
 t [tag update]          current-hackage -> current-hackage
Fetched package index.    
Populated index cache.    
stack-1.7.1: download
Could not parse '/private/var/folders/qg/f15r0d6s1gj6nsbg_517515h0000gn/T/stack-upgrade75400/stack-1.7.1/stack.yaml':
AesonException "Error in $['extra-deps'][0]: failed to parse field 'extra-deps': failed to parse field extra-deps: (Invalid package identifier: \"rio-0.1.1.0@rev:0\",\"rio-0.1.1.0@rev:0\")"
See http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/.
```

```
$ stack --resolver lts-10.10 install idris
Run from outside a project, using implicit global project config
Using latest snapshot resolver: lts-11.9
Writing implicit global project config file to: /Users/dmitrizaitsev/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml
Note: You can change the snapshot via the resolver field there.
Downloaded lts-10.10 build plan.    
AesonException "Error in $.packages.cassava.constraints.flags: failed to parse field packages: failed to parse field constraints: failed to parse field flags: Invalid flag name: \"bytestring--lt-0_10_4\""
```

---

UPDATE.
After more tries, the update seemed to work.
However, the adventure looks far from end:

```
$ cabal install idris
...
Failed to install regex-base-0.93.2
Build log ( /Users/dmitrizaitsev/.cabal/logs/regex-base-0.93.2.log ):
/Users/dmitrizaitsev/.cabal/logs/regex-base-0.93.2.log: openFile: does not
exist (No such file or directory)
```

So the build log is written to the file, but somehow that file does not exist??!!??

---

Just trying to install `idris` (on Mac OSX 10.8):

```
$ cabal update; cabal install idris
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
cabal: Failed to download http://hackage.haskell.org/00-index.tar.gz : HTTP
code 503
Warning: The package list for 'hackage.haskell.org' does not exist. Run 'cabal
update' to download it.
cabal: There is no package named 'idris'.
You may need to run 'cabal update' to get the latest list of available
packages.
```

Run `cabal update` to download list that is not available???
As response to `cabal update`?

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: 503 is the HTTP response for "The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary overload or scheduled maintenance.". Try again after a little bit of a wait and it will probably work (just tried it myself and didn't get a 503). That said, the infrastructure team should probably be notified -- perhaps they know, or perhaps they don't and Haskell has gotten popular enough that it's time to upgrade the Hackage server.

Comment: From some discussion on the #hackage IRC channel: it does seem to be somewhat known that Hackage is starting to get overloaded at popular times. Also, cabal 2.0 and later will fall back to mirrors (the recent improvements in Hackage's security design has made it safer to blindly use a mirror than it used to be), so you might consider upgrading cabal once you're able to.

Comment: @DanielWagner Thank you, I have updated the question, looks cryptic and hopeless though :(

Comment: This is a completely different question now... Anyway, it's likely a filesystem permissions error or similar. You've misunderstood what it's saying about which file does not exist. Run with a bit more verbosity to find out what it's trying to do when it fails (add `-v`, `-v2`, or `-v3` for progressively more information).

Comment: If you simply want to install the Idris compiler (as opposed to using it as a library in a Haskell program), I'd recommend side-stepping cabal hell, and just use stack to install it instead.

Comment: @Probie Still runs into errors, see the updates.

Comment: I don't know what's going on with the stack install script. What about [manually installing a newer version?](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade/#manual-download_1)

Comment: To clarify with regards to hackage, the impact from "overload" tends to be very short-lived and typically comes from crawlbots that hammer the resources and don't obey robots.txt files. We've gotten better at handling them, but it can still cause temporary problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Idris via Stack with the following commands:

1. Install Stack: `curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh`
2. Install Idris: `stack --resolver lts-10.10 install idris`

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing but cryptic errors, see the Update 2.

Comment: That's because you didn't follow the instructions I provided for installing Stack. You have an out-of-date executable from your distro's repos most likely.

Comment: I certainly did, with the message: `Stack Version 1.1.2 already appears to be installed at:
  /usr/local/bin/stack
Use 'stack upgrade' or your OS's package manager to upgrade,`

Comment: Also see UPDATE 3.

Comment: Well, that last error message means that `curl` can't download from Github. I don't really know what could be causing that, it's certainly not a Haskell-specific issue anymore.